# How do I style radio buttons with images - laughing smiley for good, sad smiley for bad?

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to create an HTML form for user feedback.
If the overall feedback is good, the user should click on a laughing smiley, if the overall feedback is bad, the user should choose a sad smiley.

I think this should be done using radio buttons, with the smileys instead of the radio buttons. Maybe I'm wrong though...

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Image instead of radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

Answer (score 68):

Let's keep them simple, shall we. First off, using pure HTML + CSS:

```
<div id="emotion">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="sad" />
        <label for="sad"><img src="sad_image.png" alt="I'm sad" /></label>

    <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="happy" />
        <label for="happy"><img src="happy_image.png" alt="I'm happy" /></label>
</div>
```

This will degrade nicely if there's no JavaScript. Use `id` and `for` attributes to link up the label and radiobutton so that when the image is selected, the corresponding radiobutton will be filled. This is important because we'll need to hide the actual radiobutton using JavaScript. Now for some jQuery goodness. First off, creating the CSS we'll need:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#emotion label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#emotion label img {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Now for the JavaScript:

```
$('#emotion input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#emotion label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

The reason why we're not using `display: none` here is for accessibility reasons. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Zgh24/1 for a live demo, with something more fancy.

Comment: The only thing you seem to be missing here is setting the appropriate input's `checked` value when the corresponding image is clicked.

Comment: @Rob clicking on `label`s would check the appropriate `input`s - no JavaScript needed. You can comment out the first line of the JavaScript code to see this.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Thanks. I modified your example slightly to make the image the clickable thing, which would be why I saw that behavior. My bad.

Comment: JavaScript is no longer needed for this. `input[type=radio]:checked + label>img` will select the image just fine. See: http://codepen.io/DavidBradbury/pen/HuCqx

Answer (score 37):

You can take advantage of CSS3 to do that, by hidding the *by-default* input radio button with CSS3 rules:

```
.class-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}
```

And then using labels for images as the following demos:

### [JSFiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/10/)

[image: From top to bottom: Unfocused, MasterCard Selected, Visa Selected, Mastercard hovered]

### [JSFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/22/)

[image: Visa selected]

## [Gist - How to use images for radio-buttons](https://gist.github.com/rcotrina94/7828886)

Comment: Great solution, but how to make it work with responsive design. In css i see .drinkcard-cc - width and height fixed..

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. Just wrap them into a responsive container, then set the width or height at 100%.

Comment: Hi @RichardCotrina is there a way of making this compatible with IE?

Comment: @Raulnd maybe setting ``display:none;`` to the ``<input>``. I can't test IE compatibility right now. Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: @RichardCotrina that hides the radio but then you wouldnt know which one is selected because both images are full color. I hope I explained myself

Comment: @Raulnd Uhmm, You should add ``-ms-filter`` filter rules for grayscale, and just in case that doesn't work, try playing with ``opacity``.

Comment: @RichardCotrina found it! opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure HTML+CSS solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-radio">
  <input type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="ice_cream" id="ice_cream_vanilla">
  <label for="ice_cream_vanilla">Vanilla</label>
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="ice_cream" id="ice_cream_chocolate">
  <label for="ice_cream_chocolate">Chocolate</label>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
  // use an image instead of the native radio widget
.image-radio {   
  input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type=radio] + label {
    background: asset-url('icons/choice-unchecked.svg') no-repeat left;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background: asset-url('icons/choice-checked.svg') no-repeat left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With pure html (no JS), you can't really substitute a radio-button for an image (at least, I don't think you can). You could, though use the following to make the same connection to the user:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
       <input type="radio" name="feeling" id="feelingSad" value="sad" /><label for="feelingSad"><img src="path/to/sad.png" /></label>
       <label for="feelingHappy"><input type="radio" name="feeling" id="feelingHappy" value="happy" /><img src="path/to/happy.png" /></label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Wrap the images in `label` elements for more semantic goodness, as well as to automatically make the buttons. Also, `alt` attributes are **mandatory**, so you'll need those too on the `img` tags.

Comment: That's what I get for rushing...thanks @Yi and @cherouvim, you're both absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited  one of the previous post. Now, it is way more simple and it works perfectly.

```
<input style="position: absolute;left:-9999px;" type="radio" name="emotion" id="sad" />
<label for="sad"><img src="red.gif" style="display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;padding: 3px;" alt="I'm sad" /></label>

<input  style="position: absolute;left:-9999px;" type="radio" name="emotion" id="happy" />
<label for="happy"><img src="blue.gif" style="display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;padding: 3px;" alt="I'm happy" /></label>
```

Comment: put a div around it and you get rid of the "invalid location for tag" message. short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style things like radio buttons, checkboxes, scrollsbars (etc.) at all.  These are native to the OS and the browser and not something you can manipulate.

You can simulate this, however by hiding the radio buttons and only showing an image instead as in.

```
<input type="radio" style="display: none;" id="sad" /><label for="sad"><img class="sad_image" /></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Keep your checkbox elements hidden and create a list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link1">Happy face</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link2">Sad face</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <!-- More code -->
    <input type="radio" id="option1" name="radio1" value="happy" style="display:none"/>
    <input type="radio" id="option2" name="radio1" value="sad" style="display:none"/>
    <!-- More code -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list li a").click(function() {
    $('#list .active').removeClass("active");
    var id = this.id;
    var newselect = id.replace('link', 'option');
    $('#'+newselect).attr('checked', true);
    $(this).addClass("active").parent().addClass("active");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

This code would add the *checked* attribute to your radio inputs in the background and assign class *active* to your list elements. Do not use inline styles of course, don't forget to include jQuery and everything should run out of the box after you customize it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is to use a form replacement script/library.
They usually hide the original element and replace them with a div or span, which you can style in whatever way you like.

Examples are:

http://customformelements.net (based on mootools)
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/481/jQuery-UI-Radiobutton-und-Checkbox-Replacement.html

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem I created a simple jQuery plugin http://xypaul.github.io/radioimg.js/

It works using hidden radio buttons and labels containing images as shown below.

```
<input type="radio" style="display: none;" id="a" />
<label for="a">
   <img class="" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Images can be placed in place of radio buttons by using label and span elements.

```
   <div class="customize-radio">
        <label>Favourite Smiley</label>
        <br>
        <label for="hahaha">
          <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="hahaha">
          <span class="haha-img"></span>
          HAHAHA
        </label>
        <label for="kiss">
          <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="kiss">
          <span class="kiss-img"></span>
          Kiss
        </label>
        <label for="tongueOut">
          <input type="radio" name="smiley" id="tongueOut">
          <span class="tongueout-img"></span>
          TongueOut
        </label>
    </div>
```

Radio button should be hidden,

```
.customize-radio label > input[type = 'radio'] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Image can be given in the span tag,

```
.customize-radio label > input[type = 'radio'] ~ span{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 27px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 27px 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.haha-img {
    background-image: url('hahabefore.png');
}

.kiss-img{
    background-image: url('kissbefore.png');
}
.tongueout-img{
    background-image: url('tongueoutbefore.png');
}
```

To change the image on click of radio button, add checked state to the input tag,

```
.customize-radio label > input[type = 'radio']:checked ~ span.haha-img{
     background-image: url('haha.png');
}
.customize-radio label > input[type = 'radio']:checked ~ span.kiss-img{
    background-image: url('kiss.png');
}
.customize-radio label > input[type = 'radio']:checked ~ span.tongueout-img{
        background-image: url('tongueout.png');
}
```

If you have any queries, Refer to the following link, As I have taken solution from the below blog,
http://frontendsupport.blogspot.com/2018/06/cool-radio-buttons-with-images.html