# CSS is not working with radio button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, radio-button

i have tried below css to show image in radio button, but following css is not working.please help.

```
.RadioButton
{
    background-image: url(../images/radio.png);
}


<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" CssClass="RadioButton"/>
```

Comment: See [**How do I style radio buttons with images**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3896259/1516616) Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style a radio button with CSS alone as their appearance is determined by the OS, not the browsers. You will have to use a Javascript plugin to allow it.

[As you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/3zChd/), the image is loaded within the `<img>` tag, but not as a background image for the radio button.

You can use a plugin [like this one](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) to be able to style these elements.

Comment: See [How do I style radio buttons with images?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3896259/1516616)

Comment: It _still_ uses Javascript. The OP asked why the CSS background image was not working. This is the reason.