# Replace Radios with Images

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I want to replace radio buttons with images, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896156/how-do-i-style-radio-buttons-with-images-laughing-smiley-for-good-sad-smiley) code but it only works with one radio group. Does anyone have another code. What I want to do: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxfH/).

```
//Group 1
<input type="radio" name="site" id="so" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Stack Overflow" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="sf" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="su" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
//Group 2
<input type="radio" name="second" id="sd" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="second" id="sc" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
```

Can anyone give me a Javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that you have changed `id` attributes for radios in second group, but labels have `for` attribute set to an id of the one of elements from the first group. Since you have hidden radios with CSS you don't see this, but clicking on labels in second group is marking radio in first group as selected. Remember to copy and paste code carefully, because you would look for a bug caused by copy and paste without updating everything needed for long hours.

Second thing - `siblings()` method returns all siblings of the element, so in your current HTML code you can see that **all** radios are siblings. I suggest you to wrap each group with, for example, `div`, so they will be separated and the JS code will be the same.

Updated HTML from question:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="so" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Stack Overflow" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="sf" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site" id="su" value="superuser" /><label for="su"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="second" id="sd" value="superuser" /><label for="sd"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="second" id="sc" value="superuser" /><label for="sc"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxfH/1/). If you want to be sure if radios are getting selected corectly, comment out line that applies CSS to hide radios to see how it behaves:

```
//$('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to save a lot of code. I had already noticed the id problem.