# ASP.NET MVC Multi-language feature does not work as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the app working using **Radio buttons** e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
<input type="radio" name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" class="culture" /> English
<input type="radio" name="culture" id="tr" value="tr" class="culture" /> Türk
}
```

but when i use **input of image type** it does not send the wanted **VALUE**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
<input type="image" src="~/Content/Images/en.png" name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" class="culture" /> 
<input type="image" src="~/Content/Images/tr.png" name="culture" id="tr" value="tr" class="culture" />
}
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(".culture").click(function () {
     $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
});
```

**HomeController Code:**

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture){
    // action code here
}
```

I see no reason why the images wouldn't work but for some reason it happens. Any ideas?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block (using `<input type="radio" .. />`), you form will only post back one value for `culture` (the value of the selected radio button).

In the second code block (using `<input type="image" .. />`) your form will post back the values of both inputs, so your form data is `culture=en-US&culture=tr`

The `DefaultModelBinder` will bind the first value and ignore the second value so the value of `culture` in the POST method will always be "en-US" irrespective of which image you click.

One option would be to disable the other input (disabled inputs do not post back a value, for example

```
$(".culture").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', true); // disable the other input
    $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
});
```

Another option for handling this is to use `<img>` tags in conjunction with a hidden input for the culture value

```
<input type="hidden" name="culture" id="culture"/>
<img src="~/Content/Images/en.png" data-culture="en-US" class="culture" />
<img src="~/Content/Images/tr.png" data-culture="tr" class="culture" />

$('.culture').click(function () {
    $('#culture').val($(this).data('culture')); // update the hidden input
    $('form').submit();
})
```

Comment: Though this makes a perfect sense the fix didn't work

Comment: Then is the code in your question the exact code in your real view (what I have shown does work)?

Comment: Yes it does work with text too (beside the radio) but i need to have flag images to be clicked. Is there another control that could possibly meet the requirements? Thx

Comment: One problem you may have is that `type="image"` will do a submit depending on the browser (i.e. your doing it twice). You can add `return false` as the last line of code in the script to prevent the default submit.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to use `type="image"` and seems to work fine.

Comment: Note I had assumed that your `type="image"` was not submitting the form, but my best guess now is that it actually is, in which case you do not need the script at all. Try commenting it out.

Comment: I disabled the script and everything but no luck. I don't know how it works for you. It keeps sending the very first value which is en-US for me

Comment: There must be something else in your code causing the issue that you have not shown us. Not only does the fiddle work, I have also created a new test project in VS with the exact code you have posted and it does work correctly (clicking on the second image posts back `"tr"`)

Comment: This is the project that i used as basis http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx i just replaced the radio buttons with inputs of image type and realize that it does not work anymore.

Comment: You can always consider styling your radio buttons as images - some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896156/how-do-i-style-radio-buttons-with-images-laughing-smiley-for-good-sad-smiley) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

Comment: Well i would like to make it working with the image input but if it's not possible i will have to check those links. Thank you so much for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have added another option to handle this.